# Why can I not run 2019 Call of Duty Modern Warfare on Wine?

Tags: wine, games, winetricks

Call of Duty Modern Warfare from Oct 2019 cannot be run.

- winepath is configured to the call of duty location with all DLLs.
- I installed wine-staging too.

Errors are:

```
0x0000000010001a80: int $3
Modules:
Module  Address                 Debug info  Name (109 modules)
PE            230000-          32f000   Deferred        oo2core_7_win64
PE            330000-          3d5000   Deferred        anselsdk64
PE            3e0000-          7ef000   Deferred        gfesdk
PE            7f0000-          81d000   Deferred        amd_ags_x64
PE            820000-          9fc000   Deferred        setupapi
PE            a00000-          a49000   Deferred        jsproxy
PE            c70000-          c7f000   Deferred        api-ms-win-core-localization-l1-2-1
PE          61340000-        6134e000   Deferred        api-ms-win-core-localization-obsolete-l1-2-0
PE          62600000-        626ef000   Deferred        usp10
PE          637c0000-        63944000   Deferred        winmm
PE          64340000-        6443e000   Deferred        winhttp
PE          64940000-        64988000   Deferred        shcore
PE          64b80000-        64bab000   Deferred        hid
PE          65000000-        655b2000   Deferred        ole32
PE          65680000-        6568f000   Deferred        api-ms-win-core-sysinfo-l1-2-1
PE          65780000-        6579f000   Deferred        version
PE          66600000-        6660e000   Deferred        api-ms-win-core-datetime-l1-1-1
PE          66780000-        6678e000   Deferred        api-ms-win-core-string-l1-1-0
PE          67500000-        67527000   Deferred        xinput9_1_0
PE          688c0000-        688e3000   Deferred        powrprof
PE          68a40000-        68b75000   Deferred        shlwapi
PE          6a100000-        6a54f000   Deferred        oleaut32
PE          6a700000-        6a725000   Deferred        aclui
PE          6b880000-        6b88e000   Deferred        api-ms-win-core-fibers-l1-1-1
PE          6bec0000-        6bf0d000   Deferred        imm32
PE          6e340000-        6e34f000   Deferred        api-ms-win-core-synch-l1-2-0
PE          6e6c0000-        6eb59000   Deferred        comctl32
PE          6fbc0000-        6fdfe000   Deferred        rpcrt4
PE          71040000-        712e2000   Deferred        kernelbase
ELF         7a800000-        7a9e3000   Deferred        opengl32<elf>
  \-PE          7a850000-        7a9e3000   \               opengl32
ELF         7b400000-        7b819000   Deferred        kernel32<elf>
  \-PE          7b420000-        7b819000   \               kernel32
ELF         7bc00000-        7bf09000   Deferred        ntdll<elf>
  \-PE          7bc20000-        7bf09000   \               ntdll
ELF         7c000000-        7c004000   Deferred        <wine-loader>
PE         140000000-       1568c6e00   Deferred        modernwarfare
PE         180000000-       18007b000   Deferred        bink2w64
ELF     7fc36d055000-    7fc36d25d000   Deferred        libffi.so.6
ELF     7fc36d25d000-    7fc36d4de000   Deferred        libgmp.so.10
ELF     7fc36d4de000-    7fc36d712000   Deferred        libhogweed.so.4
ELF     7fc36d712000-    7fc36d948000   Deferred        libnettle.so.6
ELF     7fc36d948000-    7fc36db5b000   Deferred        libtasn1.so.6
ELF     7fc36db5b000-    7fc36ded9000   Deferred        libunistring.so.2
ELF     7fc36ded9000-    7fc36e0f6000   Deferred        libidn2.so.0
ELF     7fc36e0f6000-    7fc36e425000   Deferred        libp11-kit.so.0
ELF     7fc36e425000-    7fc36e78a000   Deferred        libgnutls.so.30
ELF     7fc36e7ab000-    7fc36e7fb000   Deferred        uxtheme<elf>
  \-PE      7fc36e7b0000-    7fc36e7fb000   \               uxtheme
ELF     7fc36e7fb000-    7fc36ea01000   Deferred        libxfixes.so.3
ELF     7fc36ea01000-    7fc36ec0b000   Deferred        libxcursor.so.1
ELF     7fc36ec8a000-    7fc36eebc000   Deferred        libexpat.so.1
ELF     7fc36eebc000-    7fc36f101000   Deferred        libfontconfig.so.1
ELF     7fc36f101000-    7fc36f333000   Deferred        libpng16.so.16
ELF     7fc36f333000-    7fc36f5e7000   Deferred        libfreetype.so.6
ELF     7fc36f5e7000-    7fc36f7f7000   Deferred        libxi.so.6
ELF     7fc36f7f7000-    7fc36f9fa000   Deferred        libxcomposite.so.1
ELF     7fc36f9fa000-    7fc36fc05000   Deferred        libxrandr.so.2
ELF     7fc36fc05000-    7fc36fe0f000   Deferred        libxrender.so.1
ELF     7fc36fe0f000-    7fc370015000   Deferred        libxxf86vm.so.1
ELF     7fc370015000-    7fc370218000   Deferred        libxinerama.so.1
ELF     7fc370218000-    7fc37042d000   Deferred        libbsd.so.0
ELF     7fc37042d000-    7fc370633000   Deferred        libxdmcp.so.6
ELF     7fc370633000-    7fc370837000   Deferred        libxau.so.6
ELF     7fc370837000-    7fc370a5f000   Deferred        libxcb.so.1
ELF     7fc370a5f000-    7fc370d97000   Deferred        libx11.so.6
ELF     7fc370d97000-    7fc370fa9000   Deferred        libxext.so.6
ELF     7fc370fa9000-    7fc371071000   Deferred        winex11<elf>
  \-PE      7fc370fc0000-    7fc371071000   \               winex11
ELF     7fc371071000-    7fc37129b000   Deferred        libtinfo.so.5
ELF     7fc37129b000-    7fc3714be000   Deferred        libncurses.so.5
ELF     7fc3714df000-    7fc371505000   Deferred        bcrypt<elf>
  \-PE      7fc3714f0000-    7fc371505000   \               bcrypt
ELF     7fc371505000-    7fc371611000   Deferred        crypt32<elf>
  \-PE      7fc371510000-    7fc371611000   \               crypt32
ELF     7fc371611000-    7fc371652000   Deferred        ws2_32<elf>
  \-PE      7fc371620000-    7fc371652000   \               ws2_32
ELF     7fc371652000-    7fc37186f000   Deferred        libz.so.1
ELF     7fc371890000-    7fc37191d000   Deferred        dbghelp<elf>
  \-PE      7fc3718a0000-    7fc37191d000   \               dbghelp
ELF     7fc37191d000-    7fc371ac4000   Deferred        wined3d<elf>
  \-PE      7fc371940000-    7fc371ac4000   \               wined3d
ELF     7fc371ac4000-    7fc371afd000   Deferred        dxgi<elf>
  \-PE      7fc371ad0000-    7fc371afd000   \               dxgi
ELF     7fc371afd000-    7fc371b30000   Deferred        iphlpapi<elf>
  \-PE      7fc371b10000-    7fc371b30000   \               iphlpapi
ELF     7fc371b30000-    7fc372599000   Deferred        shell32<elf>
  \-PE      7fc371b50000-    7fc372599000   \               shell32
ELF     7fc372599000-    7fc372685000   Deferred        msvcrt<elf>
  \-PE      7fc3725c0000-    7fc372685000   \               msvcrt
ELF     7fc372685000-    7fc37271c000   Deferred        advapi32<elf>
  \-PE      7fc372690000-    7fc37271c000   \               advapi32
ELF     7fc37271c000-    7fc3728ca000   Deferred        gdi32<elf>
  \-PE      7fc372730000-    7fc3728ca000   \               gdi32
ELF     7fc3728ca000-    7fc372b5a000   Deferred        user32<elf>
  \-PE      7fc3728f0000-    7fc372b5a000   \               user32
ELF     7fc372d5a000-    7fc372f6c000   Deferred        libnss_files.so.2
ELF     7fc372f6c000-    7fc373186000   Deferred        libnsl.so.1
ELF     7fc373186000-    7fc373392000   Deferred        libnss_nis.so.2
ELF     7fc373392000-    7fc37359c000   Deferred        libnss_compat.so.2
ELF     7fc37416b000-    7fc374383000   Deferred        libgcc_s.so.1
ELF     7fc374383000-    7fc374721000   Deferred        libm.so.6
ELF     7fc374721000-    7fc374929000   Deferred        librt.so.1
ELF     7fc37492b000-    7fc374b2f000   Deferred        libdl.so.2
ELF     7fc374b2f000-    7fc374f20000   Deferred        libc.so.6
ELF     7fc374f20000-    7fc37513f000   Deferred        libpthread.so.0
ELF     7fc37514c000-    7fc375160000   Deferred        wow64cpu<elf>
  \-PE      7fc375150000-    7fc375160000   \               wow64cpu
ELF     7fc37551f000-    7fc375749000   Deferred        ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
Threads:
process  tid      prio (all id:s are in hex)
0000000e services.exe
    [C:\windows\system32\services.exe]
    00000021    0
    0000001c    0
    00000015    0
    00000010    0
    0000000f    0
00000011 plugplay.exe
    [C:\windows\system32\plugplay.exe]
    00000019    0
    00000018    0
    00000012    0
00000013 explorer.exe
    [C:\windows\system32\explorer.exe /desktop]
    00000029    0
    00000028    0
    00000027    0
    00000014    0
0000001a winedevice.exe
    [C:\windows\system32\winedevice.exe]
    0000001e    0
    0000001d    0
    0000001b    0
0000001f winedevice.exe
    [C:\windows\system32\winedevice.exe]
    00000024    0
    00000023    0
    00000022    0
    00000020    0
00000088 Agent.exe
    ["C:\ProgramData\Battle.net\Agent\Agent.6899\Agent.exe" --locale=enUS --session=6095490484801461663]
    000000a4    0
    000000a3    0
    000000a2    0
    000000a1    0
    000000a0    0
    0000009f    0
    0000009e    0
    0000009d    0
    0000009c    0
    0000009b    0
    0000009a    0
    00000099    0
    00000098    0
    00000097    0
    00000096    0
    00000095    0
    00000094    0
    00000093    0
    00000092    0
    00000091    0
    00000090    0
    0000008f    0
    0000008e    0
    0000008c    0
    00000089    0
0000008a wineconsole.exe
    [wineconsole --use-event=20]
    0000008b    0
000000a6 Battle.net.exe
    ["C:\Program Files (x86)\Battle.net\Battle.net.exe" --game=odin "--gamepath=Z:\media\windows\Documents and Settings\amazon\Desktop\call"]
    00000033    0
    0000016c   15
    00000192    0
    00000166    0
    00000139    0
    00000107    0
    000000fd    0
    000000fc    0
    000000fb    0
    000000f9    0
    000000f5    0
    000000ed    0
    000000ec    0
    000000eb   15
    000000e2    0
    000000df    0
    000000de    0
    000000dd   -2
    000000da    0
    000000d9    0
    000000d8    0
    000000d7    0
    000000d6    0
    000000d5    0
    000000d0    0
    000000cf    0
    000000ce    0
    000000cd    0
    000000cc    0
    000000cb    0
    000000ca    0
    000000c9    0
    000000c8    0
    000000c7   -2
    000000c5    0
    000000c4    0
    000000c3    0
    000000c2    0
    000000c1    0
    000000c0    0
    000000bf    0
    000000be    0
    000000bd    0
    000000bc    0
    000000bb    0
    000000ba    0
    000000b9   15
    000000b8    0
    000000b7    0
    000000b6    0
    000000b5    0
    000000b4    0
    000000b2    0
    000000b1    0
    000000b0    0
    000000af    0
    000000ae    0
    000000aa    0
    000000a7    0
000000db Battle.net.exe
    ["C:\Program Files (x86)\Battle.net\Battle.net.exe" --type=gpu-process --field-trial-handle=928,5520562833525244587,1193407397235383990,131072 --disable-features=HardwareMediaKeyHandling --no-sandbox --log-file="C:\users\amazon\Local Settings\Application Data\Battle.net\Logs\libcef-20191203T151649.228128.log" --log-severity=error --product-version="Battle.net/1.18.0.11698 Chrome/75.0.3770.100" --lang=en-US --watch-browser-pid=166 --gpu-preferences=KAAAAAAAAADgAAAgAQAAAAAAAAAAAGAAAAAAAAAAAAAIAAAAAAAAACgAAAAEAAAAIAAAAAAAAAAoAAAAAAAAADAAAAAAAAAAOAAAAAAAAAAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAFAAAAEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABgAAABAAAAAAAAAAAQAAAAUAAAAQAAAAAAAAAAEAAAAGAAAA --log-file="C:\users\amazon\Local Settings\Application Data\Battle.net\Logs\libcef-20191203T151649.228128.log" --service-request-channel-token=5453983394330561501 --mojo-platform-channel-handle=936 /prefetch:2 --battle-net-helper=Battle.net.11698]
    00000118    0
    00000117    0
    00000116    0
    00000115    0
    00000114    0
    00000113    0
    00000112   -2
    00000111    0
    00000110    0
    00000103    0
    00000102    0
    000000dc    0
000000fe Battle.net.exe
    ["C:\Program Files (x86)\Battle.net\Battle.net.exe" --type=utility --field-trial-handle=928,5520562833525244587,1193407397235383990,131072 --disable-features=HardwareMediaKeyHandling --lang=en-US --service-sandbox-type=network --no-sandbox --log-file="C:\users\amazon\Local Settings\Application Data\Battle.net\Logs\libcef-20191203T151649.228128.log" --log-severity=error --product-version="Battle.net/1.18.0.11698 Chrome/75.0.3770.100" --lang=en-US --watch-browser-pid=166 --log-file="C:\users\amazon\Local Settings\Application Data\Battle.net\Logs\libcef-20191203T151649.228128.log" --service-request-channel-token=13984087881720044706 --mojo-platform-channel-handle=1304 /prefetch:8 --battle-net-helper=Battle.net.11698]
    0000012e    0
    00000130    0
    0000012d    0
    0000012c    0
    00000128   -2
    00000127    0
    00000126    0
    00000125    0
    00000124    0
    00000123    0
    00000120    0
    0000011d    0
    0000011c    0
    000000ff    0
0000002f (D) Z:\media\windows\Documents and Settings\amazon\Desktop\call\ModernWarfare.exe
    ["Z:\media\windows\Documents and Settings\amazon\Desktop\call\ModernWarfare.exe"]
    00000042    0
    0000002e    0 <==
0000002b explorer.exe
    [C:\windows\system32\explorer.exe /desktop]
    00000036    0
    00000037    0
    00000035    0
    0000002a    0
System information:
    Wine build: wine-4.21 (Staging)
    Platform: x86_64
    Version: Windows 10
    Host system: Linux
    Host version: 5.0.0-36-generic
```

Comment: Wine is not a sure-fire way to run every program that exists.  You may wish to refer to the [AppDB entry for this](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=38451) and also corresponding runtime exception bugs listed in that page as well for details as to what the problem might be.  This said, battle-net tend sto have issues on Wine anyways, so it's less likely an issue with Ubuntu and an incompatibility with Wine and COD:MW.  (In which case, you have to let Wine handle the problems and make it compatible.).

Comment: battle-net checks for licenses and does this such that it uses different style methods on each update.  They want you to use a bought copy and to use Windows.

Answer (score 3):

I think you cannot! There is so many libraries that wasn't yet "translated" to wine environment. So, running this game in a Linux workstation is not possible yet.